# How do you make a vector animation "particle system" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

On [Stripe's homepage](https://stripe.com/) they have this incredible animation. How do you systematically make something like this in CSS/JS?

[image]

I see two main things going on:

1. A "particle system" ejecting little icons out at a random heading, with rotation and a decaying opacity. In the DOM it looks like this:

[image]

2. The rotating gears, which are a path element with an animated rotation transform

[image]

How would you set about systematically programming something like this? Are there javascript libraries that enable things like the looping animations, reuse of large numbers of small elements (sprites?) and the like?

Comment: You can use a SVG and animate it with CSS :)